# Alternative CSS tags to "display:none;" for SEO

Tags: seo

I have always made my pages "by hand". just coding them, a bit of javascript here and there.

And because I like to experiment with designs, i use a lot of popup divs, which means i use "display:none" tags for those divs.

I've been told that this could be hurting my searchability. The pages have been online for a long time. does anyone have some advice on this?

Someone has been mentioned that I will have difficulty with SEO and that I need to use a CMS like wordpress.

what do you think my next move should be?

Is there something in my CSS I can change, or do I go the CMS route?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Google stated that content hidden for UX should have full weight. In other words, using `display:none` will no longer have a negative impact.

In my opinion, as long as the hidden content does not contain a list of obvious spam keywords there is no issue. I would still try and have content completely visible whenever possible.

Fun fact: Google's own search engine page uses `display:none`.